# Questions regarding react in django or react as standalone

Tags: python, reactjs, django, react-native, session-cookies

I am creating an website using react and Django. To combine Django and react there are 2 ways

> 1. React in its own “frontend” Django app: load a single HTML template
>    and let React manage the frontend (difficulty: medium)
> 2. Django REST as a standalone API + React as a standalone SPA (difficulty: hard, it
>    involves JWT for authentication)

Now my questions are

1. What are security concerns related to both and which of them is more secure way to do it.
2. In Option-1 we can use both session and token based authentication while in Option-2 we must use token based authentication and XSRF header is needed. Is session based auth better and in what factors it effects
3. If in future I plan to move to react Native for mobile app, which would be more suitable. (I could not find any example when using Option-1)
4. Apparently, Instagram is using session based auth, which means they have used Option-1. Are Option-1 sites SPA based and is Insta SPA based.
   An extra unrelated question, which is better JWT token auth or Django knox auth. If JWT is better please refer any guide on integrating it with Django.

If someone does not have complete answer and knows just any of them, please share.